# What kind of masks are the British border control officers wearing at the Gibraltar Border?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, gibraltar

When I crossed the Spanish-Gibraltarian border, the British officer was wearing a mask that seems like a replica of the mask worn by Hannibal Lecter in the movie Silence of the Lambs. 
It looked weird and in a way also funny. Unfortunately, there was no opportunity to take a picture.

Why are they wearing masks? @hippietrail provided me with a picture. I am refering to this mask.
[image]

Comment: You probably saw the N95 Protective Face Mask or a variant. These are made by the 3M company and supplied to the UK via contract. See http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Ebola-Virus-Protective-face-mask-n95_60044299072.html  They use different models so only a photo will nail it down conclusively

Comment: [Plagiarism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is [not cool](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134715).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mask shown in the picture is an anti-pollution mask (See [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HVDSLC8)).

Furthermore, the city with the worst air pollution in Spain is La Linea de la Concepción as of 2014 ([Respro Bulletin Board](http://respromask.wordpress.com/2014/05/19/todays-news-la-linea-tops-spanish-air-pollution-blacklist/), and also confirmed on the WHO website ([downloadable Excel document](http://search.who.int/search?q=spain%20air%20pollution&ie=utf8&site=who&client=_en_r&proxystylesheet=_en_r&output=xml_no_dtd&oe=utf8&getfields=doctype))).

La Linea de la Conepción is the city on the Spanish side of the Spanish-Gibraltarian border.

Therefore, I think it is safe to assume that the police officers were wearing the masks for personal protection against the bad air-pollution in the area.

Comment: I agree, considering the lengthy queues at the Spanish border getting out of Gibraltar, with five lanes of cars completely static but with the engine being kept running for the air conditioning.